# Why laravel function lists is not occupying the right option value of a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I have a dropdown that shows a name and an id from my database. The name correctly shows in the dropdown but their option value which is their ids are not correct. What is wrong with this? Please help. Thanks. Here is my code.

```
$items = App\Supplier\Supplier::lists('name', 'id');
$items->prepend('None');
```

Output:

```
<option value="0">None</option><option value="1">MT CARMEL PHARMACY INC</option><option value="2">MUREX DIAGNOSTIC PRODUCT SPECIALIST</option>
```

MT CARMEL PHARMACY INC should have a 3 option value because it is its corresponding id in the database, MUREX DIAGNOSTIC PRODUCT SPECIALIST should be 8. What should I do with this?

When I switch id and name, it shows the right values.

```
$items = App\Supplier\Supplier::lists('id', 'name');
$items->prepend('None');
```

Output:

```
<option value="0">None</option><option value="MT CARMEL PHARMACY INC">3</option><option value="MUREX DIAGNOSTIC PRODUCT SPECIALIST">8</option>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `App\Supplier\Supplier::all()->pluck('name', 'id')` (or `lists` depending on your Laravel version)?

Comment: I am using laravel 5.2 and I tried pluck but I still get the same thing.

Comment: But if I do it in other way switching the name and id, lists('id','name'), it shows the correct values.

Comment: Please help me everyone :(

Comment: Could you `dd(App\Supplier\Supplier::all()`?

Comment: Is this a bug??

Comment: Don't think that it is a bug. What results does that `dd(...)` give you?